# Can trim() and strip_tags() prevent sql injection in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Is using trim() and strip_tags() for preventing sql injection is as okay as PDO or Prepaid Statement?
thre is another question on how to prevent sql injection. trim() and strip_tags() was not even discussed there.
I dont know from where people saying duplicate finding about trim() and strip_tags() in the former question answer!? Go read the answers and my question again

```php
     $username = strip_tags(trim($_POST["username"]));
     $password = strip_tags(trim($_POST["password"]));
```

Comment: `trim()` is used to strip the white space from a string, `strip_tags()` is used to strip HTML tags from a string, they are not used for preventing SQL injection. Those methods can't protect you from special characters that can be interpretered as a part of the sql command.

Answer (score 1):

No, the best way to prevent SQL injection is by using prepared statements and parameterized queries.

you can refer to this question. [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I sugest using PDO if you are developing core php apps